# React JSX - Do we have any cli that supports components creation with .jsx file extension?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, code-generation

I have created a  new react application and it comes with initial code. I just want to create jsx components through CLI which comes with jsx extension.  I tried with command **npx generate-react-cli component MainContainer** but its generating .js files only.
Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[generate-react-cli v5.1.0](https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli) now supports custom extensions via [custom component templates](https://github.com/arminbro/generate-react-cli#custom-component-templates). You should now be able to declare a custom component template with the `jsx` extension within your `generate-react-cli.json` config file.

**Example:**

`generate-react-cli.json`

```json
{
  "usesTypeScript": false,
  "usesCssModule": true,
  "cssPreprocessor": "scss",
  "testLibrary": "Testing Library",
  "component": {
    "default": {
      "customTemplates": {
        "component": "templates/component/component.jsx"
      },
      "path": "src/components",
      "withStyle": true,
      "withTest": true,
      "withStory": true,
      "withLazy": false
    }
  }
}
```

`templates/component/component.jsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './TemplateName.module.css';

const TemplateName = () => (
  <div className={styles.TemplateName} data-testid="TemplateName">
    <h1>TemplateName component</h1>
  </div>
);

export default TemplateName;
```

Comment: so do I have to add this to every project? Or can I add this to a global setting somehow so no matter what where I use GRC it'll create a JSX file?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Hygen](https://github.com/jondot/hygen), which is a code generator and with it you can build your own react component templates

Also here is a library with everything already settled up https://www.npmjs.com/package/hygen-react